# Handling a few different types of data

Tags: php

What is the best way to handle a link that has a video within and then embed it?

I considered storing the link in the database and then showing it embedded.
How could I write code to handle the embedded side of the link?

Comment: Links don't have video within them.

Comment: I know but if I literally just use a link youtube provides within the html, will it automatically embed them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $youtube_link contains link gotten from DB, then it would look like this:

```
<?php
echo '<object width="640" height="385">
<param name="movie" value="'.$youtube_link.'"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="'.$youtube_link.'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="385"></embed></object>';
?>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, I am very grateful for this. I will attempt to use this code and come back if I have any problems.